# How to parse XML to Java object with Digester

Tags: java, xml, apache

I am using apache Digester parse XML to object. I have the following XML element:

```
<a type="X" xname = "...">..<a>
<a type="T" tname = "...">..<a>
```

I have class

```
public class X{
  private String xname;
  public static class T{
     private String tname;
  }

}
```

Is it able to if the type is X then I create class X, if type is T then create class T, notice T is public inner and child class of X. if yes, how to define the rule. I am using Digester 2.x, or introduce some better design